# Getting sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: user.image_file

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to learning Flask. following youtube tutorial, I did the same as the trainer did. But I am getting the Integrity error.

Flask_Blog.Py:

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, flash, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.com import dynamic

from forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '5791628bb0b13ce0c676dfde280ba245'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}')"


posts = [
    {
        'author': 'Corey Schafer',
        'title': 'Blog Post 1',
        'content': 'First post content',
        'date_posted': 'April 20, 2018'
    },
    {
        'author': 'Jane Doe',
        'title': 'Blog Post 2',
        'content': 'Second post content',
        'date_posted': 'April 21, 2018'
    }
]


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)


@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template('about.html', title='About')


@app.route("/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash(f'Account created for {form.username.data}!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)


@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.email.data == 'admin@blog.com' and form.password.data == 'password':
            flash('You have been logged in!', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            flash('Login Unsuccessful. Please check username and password', 'danger')
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)

 if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

This the commands I am trying to execute.
Commands:

```
**from Flask_Blog import db
db.create_all()
from Flask_Blog import User, Post
user_1 = User(username='Strange', email='doctor@strange.com', password='password')
db.session.add(user_1)
db.session.commit()**
```

After executing commit I am getting below error.

- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1819, in _execute_context
  self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 732, in do_execute
  cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: user.image_file
  The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
  exec(code, self.locals)
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "", line 2, in commit
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1435, in commit
  self._transaction.commit(_to_root=self.future)
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 829, in commit
  self._prepare_impl()
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 808, in _prepare_impl
  self.session.flush()
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 3367, in flush
  self.*flush(objects)
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 3506, in *flush
  with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in **exit**
  compat.raise*(
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise*
  raise exception
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 3467, in _flush
  flush_context.execute()
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 456, in execute
  rec.execute(self)
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 630, in execute
  util.preloaded.orm_persistence.save_obj(
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\persistence.py", line 245, in save_obj
  _emit_insert_statements(
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\persistence.py", line 1238, in _emit_insert_statements
  result = connection._execute_20(
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1631, in _execute_20
  return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 325, in _execute_on_connection
  return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1498, in _execute_clauseelement
  ret = self._execute_context(
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1862, in _execute_context
  self.*handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2043, in *handle_dbapi_exception
  util.raise*(
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise*
  raise exception
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1819, in _execute_context
  self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 732, in do_execute
  cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: user.image_file
  [SQL: INSERT INTO user (username, email, image_file, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]
  [parameters: ('Strange', 'doctor@strange.com', None, 'password')]
  (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1819, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: user.image_file
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 2, in commit
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1435, in commit
    self._transaction.commit(_to_root=self.future)
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 829, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 808, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 3367, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 3506, in _flush
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 3467, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 456, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 630, in execute
    util.preloaded.orm_persistence.save_obj(
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\persistence.py", line 245, in save_obj
    _emit_insert_statements(
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\persistence.py", line 1238, in _emit_insert_statements
    result = connection._execute_20(
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1631, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 325, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1498, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1862, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2043, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1819, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "C:\Users\darjunku\PycharmProjects\Working_with_Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: user.image_file
[SQL: INSERT INTO user (username, email, image_file, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('Corey', 'C@demo.com', None, 'password')]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=True)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?